# Query that returns the sum of accounts specified in another table where accounts to sum or range is defined

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table that users are maintaining, where they pr. statistical account can define which accounts they want to sum up - either as specified or as a range. How can you construct a view that best sums up the amount pr stat account and month. I need to somehow pr. account be able to change the where clause.

Below i have the two tables: DimStatAccount and FactAmount and below is the expected view

[image: Show input tables and expected output view]

Comment: What have you tried? Any research? Do the tables have schemas? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Appears you want to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I agree with @xQbert, a sproc with dynamic SQL would be fairly simple to throw together for this.

Comment: Just be sure the inputs to Accounts and Account Range are well sanitized.

Comment: That's a good point @xQbert, my answer would definitely fall apart if those aren't populated correctly. I also used CONCAT() which assumes SQL Server 2012 or later, but you can adjust to ISNULL() and + concatenation if using an earlier version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stole the table loads from Kevin's answer. You can use the ability to select into variables to create a dynamic SQL select statement from your DimStatAccount table.

```
CREATE TABLE DimStatAccount (StatAccount varchar(255), Accounts varchar(255), AccountsRange varchar(255))
INSERT INTO DimStatAccount VALUES
  ('Stat1', 'in (1000,1020)', null),
  ('Stat2', 'in (1020,2020)', null),
  ('Stat3', null, 'between 1000 and 1999'),
  ('Stat4', null, 'between 2000 and 2999')

CREATE TABLE FactAmount (Account int, [Month] varchar(255), Amount int)
INSERT INTO FactAmount VALUES
  (1000,'jan',500),
  (1000,'feb',460),
  (1010,'jan',799),
  (1010,'jan',855),
  (1010,'feb',633),
  (1020,'feb',522),
  (2000,'jan',436),
  (2000,'jan',946),
  (2000,'jan',374),
  (2010,'jan',683),
  (2010,'feb',492),
  (2020,'jan',437),
  (2020,'feb',834),
  (2030,'jan',944)

DECLARE @sqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sqlStatement += CONCAT('SELECT ''',StatAccount,''',[Month],SUM(Amount) FROM FactAmount WHERE Account ',ISNULL(Accounts,AccountsRange),' GROUP BY [Month] UNION ALL ')
FROM DimStatAccount
;

SET @sqlStatement = LEFT(@sqlStatement,LEN(@sqlStatement)-10); --remove the final Union All

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStatement;
```

Comment: Much simpeler than mine. Nice. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Thanks, only problem is to be able to have a view that can return this result. I guess it's not possible to make a view that exec a stored procedure?

Comment: You could make a view, but your problem is that it would have to change everytime the Dimension table was updated. So, at worst you could trigger the table to recreate a view whenever that table is changed.

Answer (score 0):

like already been said, dynamic sql is what you need.

```
CREATE TABLE #dimStatAccount (StatAccount varchar(255), Accounts varchar(255), AccountsRange varchar(255))
INSERT INTO #dimStatAccount VALUES
  ('Stat1', 'in (1000,1020)', null),
  ('Stat2', 'in (1020,2020)', null),
  ('Stat3', null, 'between 1000 and 1999'),
  ('Stat4', null, 'between 2000 and 2999')

CREATE TABLE #factAmount (Account int, [Month] varchar(255), Amount int)
INSERT INTO #factAmount VALUES
  (1000,'jan',500),
  (1000,'feb',460),
  (1010,'jan',799),
  (1010,'jan',855),
  (1010,'feb',633),
  (1020,'feb',522),
  (2000,'jan',436),
  (2000,'jan',946),
  (2000,'jan',374),
  (2010,'jan',683),
  (2010,'feb',492),
  (2020,'jan',437),
  (2020,'feb',834),
  (2030,'jan',944)

CREATE TABLE #result (StatAccount varchar(255), [Month] varchar(255), SumAmount int)

DECLARE @statAccount varchar(255), @accounts varchar(255), @rangeAccounts varchar(255)

DECLARE rcursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT StatAccount, Accounts, AccountsRange
  FROM #dimStatAccount
OPEN rcursor
FETCH NEXT FROM rcursor
INTO @statAccount, @accounts, @rangeAccounts

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)
  IF @accounts IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    SET @Sql = 'INSERT INTO #result '
    SET @sql = @Sql + 'SELECT ''' + @statAccount + ''' AS StatAccount, [MONTH], SUM(f.Amount) AS SumAmount '
    SET @Sql = @Sql + 'FROM #factAmount AS f '
    SET @Sql = @Sql +  'WHERE Account ' + @accounts + ' ' 
    SET @Sql = @Sql +  'GROUP BY [Month]'

    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM rcursor
    INTO @statAccount, @accounts, @rangeAccounts
  END   
  IF @rangeAccounts IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    SET @Sql = 'INSERT INTO #result '
    SET @sql = @Sql + 'SELECT ''' + @statAccount + ''' AS StatAccount, [MONTH], SUM(f.Amount) AS SumAmount '
    SET @Sql = @Sql + 'FROM #factAmount AS f '
    SET @Sql = @Sql +  'WHERE Account ' + @rangeAccounts + ' ' 
    SET @Sql = @Sql +  'GROUP BY [Month]'
    print @Sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM rcursor
    INTO @statAccount, @accounts, @rangeAccounts
  END
END

CLOSE rcursor 
DEALLOCATE rcursor 

SELECT * FROM #result
```

Result

```
StatAccount  Month  SumAmount
-----------------------------
Stat1        feb    982
Stat1        jan    500
Stat2        feb    1356
Stat2        jan    437
Stat3        feb    1615
Stat3        jan    2154
Stat4        feb    1326
Stat4        jan    3820
```

Comment: Thanks for writing the inserts to the original tables, hate doing that part. However, there is no need for cursors or temp tables; a simple dynamic SQL select will solve this problem